# Azure Worker Role performance is not consistent- Issue

Tags: azure, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles, azure-servicebus-queues

I have Azure Worker Role and Web Role with ExtraSmall Instance.

I m passing  Service Bus BrokeredMessage to update entity from Azure Web Role.

I just tested with updating entity, It took 5 seconds to reflect in the database for first three times.
after that it took more than 30 seconds for each updates. I don't know why the performance is not consistent in Azure Worker Role? If Anybody knows Please share your thoughts.

I m sending and receiving messages synchronously.

Note: Worker role, I m connecting the database for each updates

Code sample WorkerRole class

```
public override void Run()
{
 while (true)
  {
   receivedmsg = CUDClient.Receive();
   UpdateProjectEntity(receivedmsg);
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
private void UpdateProjectEntity (BrokeredMessage msg)
{       
  ProjectModel model = msg.GetBody<ProjectModel>();
  //connect federation database
  CrmEntities _db = Azure.ConnectCustomerEntity(model.ShardId);
  //update entities 
  ....
 }
```

Comment: For better understanding of your problem can you update your question and put a bit more on your system architecture please e.g. how a message is getting into your database etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically Synchronous receive message, thats why slow. I converted in to Aynchronous Receive message, The performance is excellent. See the post here

[Azure Worker Role Asynchronous Receive message: how long I should put the sleep for? (milliseconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502891/azure-worker-role-asynchronous-receive-message-how-long-i-should-put-the-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be that you share physical computer with 7 heavy instances. When they work a lot your instance gets slow. However,5 seconds to 30 seconds seems a lot. Can you upgrade to use an own instance, test again and then see if performance is more even?

Comment: No its not the case. web role, worker role and SQL Azure are running in Windows Azure environment.

Comment: Yes, and one physical machine on azure consists of 8 instances. Each of your services occupies one instance.

Comment: I dont know how to upgrade to use an own instance? Could you help me?

Comment: Here is the msdn guide to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee517255.aspx

Comment: Just to make sure, do you get the same behaviour in your developemnt environment?

Comment: Come to think of it, I really dont believe in this solution anymore. The behaviour rather indicates there is something that clogs the system when you use it. You should conisder providing a more comprehensial description of what you are doing and what worloads you are working with.