# Azure Worker Role Asynchronous Receive message: how long I should put the sleep for? (milliseconds)

Tags: azure, entity-framework-5, azure-worker-roles

Sample code here

```
public override void Run()
{
   while (true)
   {
    IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),  OnMessageReceive, CUDClient);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
}
```

I have tested this Azure worker role. I kept 100 messages in the Service bus Queue. It's doing entities updates as a operation(Entity framework). It took 15 minutes to process all the queues and looks like taking longer time.  Any suggestion to improve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...

```
  //Somefunction
    IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(OnMessageReceive, CUDClient); 

    while (true)
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //In case you are using thread

    //Somefunction End

public static void OnMessageReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        CUDClient.BeginReceive(OnMessageReceive, CUDClient);
        SubscriptionClient queueClient = (SubscriptionClient)result.AsyncState;
        IBusinessLogicProvider Obj;
        try
        {
            //Receive the message with the EndReceive call
            BrokeredMessage receivedmsg = queueClient.EndReceive(result);
                //receivedmsg = CUDClient.Receive();
                if (receivedmsg != null)
                {
                    switch (receivedmsg.ContentType)
                    {
                        case "Project":
                            Obj = new ProjectsBL();
                            Obj.HandleMessage(receivedmsg);
                            receivedmsg.BeginComplete(OnMessageComplete, receivedmsg);
                            break;
                     }
                 }
          }
    }
```

Comment: IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(OnMessageReceive, CUDClient); 
    while (true){};  Executed 100msgs to 30 seconds. Its the fastest in all my tries. But one question will it impact of CPU performance?

Comment: for better CPU performance,try Thread.Sleep with TimeSpan.MaxValue.

Comment: No. It should be  Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); If we leave While(true){} like that, CPU percentage was 99% .After implementing this While(true){Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);}. CPU Percentage dropped to 1%.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Service Bus is very fast enough in my experience. What wrong with you is "Thread.Sleep(10000)";

Sleeping 10 sec for each message.
 For 100 messages 100*10 = 10000 seconds = 16.67 minutes
 So this is a problem for the delay...

Solution:

Dont use Thread.Sleep(10000); (Its not suitable for BeginReceive, only suitable for Receive)

```
public override void Run() //This should not be a Thread...If its a thread then your thread will terminate after receiving your first message
{
    IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(**TimeSpan.MaxValue**,  OnMessageReceive, CUDClient);
}

//Function OnMessageReceive
{
 //Process the Message
 **IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.MaxValue,  OnMessageReceive, CUDClient);**
}
```

using TimeSpan.MaxValue your connection to the SB will be preserved for longtime. so no frequent null message(less cost)...

Comment: thanks NavaRajan, I dint find TimeSpan.MaxLimit. So used TimeSpan.MaxValue. Its taking longer time.  Do I need to use - while (true)
   { }

Comment: infinite loop is not needed... Once you get callback(ie message received) you are going to beginReceive in the callback itself..so you will be continuously listening on the SB end... If you cant understand it i will explain you better...

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion. I placed 10 messages in queue, It took 7 mins 30 seconds. Its too slow.

Comment: @sivaL I think processing the messages are taking the time. Dont Process the message in the onMessageReceive(start some thread for that).

Answer (score 1):

Try using **XecMe** Parallel task for processing the message reading.

XecMe @ xecme.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.

```
while (true)
        {
           //read all topic messages in sequential way....           
           IAsyncResult result = CUDClient.BeginReceive(OnMessageReceive, CUDClient); 
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }  
public static void OnMessageReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        SubscriptionClient queueClient = (SubscriptionClient)result.AsyncState;
        IBusinessLogicProvider Obj;
        try
        {
            //Receive the message with the EndReceive call
            BrokeredMessage receivedmsg = queueClient.EndReceive(result);
                //receivedmsg = CUDClient.Receive();
                if (receivedmsg != null)
                {
                    switch (receivedmsg.ContentType)
                    {
                        case "Project":
                            Obj = new ProjectsBL();
                            Obj.HandleMessage(receivedmsg);
                            receivedmsg.BeginComplete(OnMessageComplete, receivedmsg);
                            break;
                     }
                 }
          }
    }
```

It processed all the 100 messages in 1 minute(00:01:02) . A lot better than previous one.

Comment: Please put OnMessageReceive Code... I think you are having bad assumption about thread...

Comment: I updated OnMessageRececeive method code. I tried with different thread for this method and implemented TimeSpan.MaxValue. No improvement in the performance. If you feel like its not the right approach. Please post working code for the above in different answer.